# How do I keep files in a branch if they are removed from master?

Tags: git, github

I have to checkout to master and pull changes, but in those changes, a few of the files I was working on have been removed and new files made. I want to keep those files in my branch and push them to master again.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a flaw in this question, which we can demonstrate:

```
$ cd ~/tmp && mkdir x && cd x && git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ echo demonstrate that files are not in branches > README
$ git add README && git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) 7490a25] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
$ echo file 1 > file1
$ echo file 2 > file2
$ git add file1 file2
$ git commit -m 'add some files'
[master 5b25569] add some files
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 file1
 create mode 100644 file2
$ git rm file1 
rm 'file1'
$ git commit -m 'remove file1'
[master 15f7d52] remove file1
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
 delete mode 100644 file1
$ ls
file2   README
$ git branch -a
* master
```

Exercises:

1. How many branches are there?
2. Which branch has `file1` in it? (This is a trick question)
3. What files are in branch `master`? (This is also a trick question)

Before you read any others answers here, see what your own answers are.

I might use the spoiler hide/reveal trick from some of the other StackExchange sites, if they worked here, but they don't, so just try not to peek too far down to actual answers, where I discuss the fact that questions two and three are trick questions.  For that matter, question one is a bit of a trick too.

#### Some wrong answers, but hey, they're trick questions...

OK, so, first: the obvious answers are:

1. 1
2. `master`
3. `file2` and `README`.

And yet if `file1` is in branch `master`, where is it?  If it's *not* in `master`, *where is it?*

#### The trick

The trick here is that Git is not about *files*.  It's true that Git *stores* files, but it stores them in commits.  And Git is not even about *branches*, although we use *branch names* to *find* commits.

The best answer to Q1 is that there's one branch *name*.  How many *branches* there are depends on how we define the word *branch*.  Some definitions will still get us `1` as the answer; another would get us 3 because there are three commits, hence three things that are at least *potential* branches; and another would get us "infinity" because once there's at least one commit, there are an infinite number of possible branch names.  (Well, not *quite* infinite, because our computers are finite, but more than we want to bother trying to count.)

The best answers to Q2 and Q3, though, are just [mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)): files are not *in* branches, in Git.  Files are in *commits*.

In the output above—if you repeat the commands, you'll get different commit hashes, so yours will be slightly different—the file `file1` is in *commit 5b25569*.  That commit is *contained in* branch `master`, but it is just one of three commits in `master`.  The file `file2` is in commits 5b25569 and 15f7d52, and both of these commits are in `master`; and `README` is in all three commits, including the initial root commit 7490a25.

#### So now we know the trick

The trick is that files are not in *branches*, but rather in *commits*.  The commits themselves are contained in branches—meaning *found by using those branch names*—but the files are in the *commits*.  "Later" commits may have more files, or fewer files, or just different files, than "earlier" commits.  So, let's go back to the original problem statement now:

> I have to checkout to master and pull changes,

Technically, you don't *have to* do any of this, you just *want to*.  But let's assume that this is a good plan—and for the most part, it is.  The next thing you should know, though, is that the phrase *pull changes* is as misleading as the question about which branch some file is in.  You are talking about running `git pull`, and the `pull` command is just shorthand for running two *other* Git commands:

1. `git fetch`: this obtains any commits that are *new to you;*
2. some second Git command to incorporate those new commits into the *current branch*.

> but in those changes, a few of the files I was working on have been removed and new files made.

Now that you know that files are in *commits*, the next key realization is that `git fetch` merely *adds commits to your collection*.  All your *existing* commits remain intact.  The *second* command you'll run could change this, depending on which second command you choose; that's where lal the complications come in.

> I want to keep those files in my branch and push them to master again.

As long as you keep all your *own* commits, and all the earlier commits, you will be able to get to those files.  The reason for that is simple: *any commit, once made, is completely read-only.*  So the files saved inside a commit are saved *forever*—or at least, as long as that commit continues to exist.

#### How commits work

Now that you know that Git is all about *commits*, it's important to understand how you will use them and work with them.  The next two things you should probably do at this point are run `git log`, and maybe `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`.  See also [Pretty Git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452).  Here, though, let's discuss what a commit is and does for you.

- Each commit is numbered.  These numbers are not simple counting numbers: we don't have commit #1, followed by commit #2, then #3 and so on.  Instead, the numbers are huge and ugly, and impossible for humans to remember or deal with.  The actual number of any one commit is simply a cryptographic hash of the commit's contents (as seen as an internal Git object), expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).  It *looks* random, though it is not.  Git guarantees that *every* commit everywhere gets a totally unique number.
- Each commit stores two things:

  - A commit stores a full snapshot of every file.  The files are saved inside—or in a sense, *outside*—the commit in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and *de-duplicated* form.  This takes care of the fact that commits tend to re-use a lot of files.  In the example above, the `README` file was the same in all three commits.  In fact, there was really only *one* `README` file-content ever saved; all three commits just referred to this same file (as a hash ID: `f17a15bb99297d320e9a001a39052d43b17b2ce2`).
  - Each commit stores some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  The metadata inside a commit contains things like the name and email address of the person who made the commit.  It also contains some date-and-time-stamps, which help make sure the commit gets a unique hash ID.  (Otherwise, if you used an empty commit as the first commit of every repository, all your initial root commits would have the same hash ID!)

  Importantly for Git's internal operation, each commit stores, in its metadata, the hash ID of some set of *earlier* commits.  (This set is empty for the very first commit, since it *is* the first commit: there is no earlier commit.)  Most commits store just one previous, or *parent*, hash ID; we call these *ordinary* commits.

So, if we have a simple chain of ordinary commits, each one has the raw hash ID of the *previous* ordinary commit.  That is, if the most recent commit has hash ID `H`, commit `H` has inside it the hash ID of some earlier commit.  We say that `H` *points to* this earlier commit, and we can draw that, like this:

```
            <-H
```

If we call that earlier commit `G`, we can add that in to our drawing:

```
        <-G <-H
```

Since commit `G` points to an earlier commit, if we call that commit `F`, we draw that in:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

and so on, all the way back to the very first commit (a *root commit*—that's why Git said `[master (root-commit) 7490a25] initial` way back when).

#### Branch names let us find commits

When we first start out, we have no commits at all:

```
(kind of an uninteresting graphic here)
```

We make our first, or *root*, commit, maybe with a `README` file like I did:

```
A
```

There's only the one commit, which doesn't point anywhere, so obviously we're using just that one commit.  But we'll change that soon, so let's draw in the name `master` and make `master` point to `A`:

```
A   <-- master
```

Now let's make our *second* commit, `B` (`[master 5b25569] add some files`), which points back to `A`.  When we do that, Git changes our name `master` to point to `B` instead of `A`, with `B` pointing back to existing commit `A`:

```
A <-B   <-- master
```

We'll repeat with another commit (`[master 15f7d52] remove file1`):

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

We're getting a little bit tired so we stop bothering drawing in the arrows from commits to commits *as* arrows.  They can't *change* after we make the commits: all commits are completely read-only, forever, so we don't really need to bother.

#### Note how the branch name advances as we go

We started with the name `master` pointing to `A`, when we made our root commit.  Then we made commit `B` and Git updated our name `master` to point to `B` instead of `A`.  Once we made commit `C`, `C` pointed to `B` and `master` pointed to `C`.

If we now decide that we want to *get rid of* commit `C`, we can use `git reset --hard`, which normally we wouldn't do because it throws some work away.  But in this case that work is just "remove a file", so we might not mind.  To make this `git reset` work, we have to find the hash ID of commit `B`.  We tell Git to make the name `master` point directly to `B`, instead of `C`, and we get:

```
     C   [abandoned]
    /
A--B   <-- master
```

Commit `C` is not *gone*.  It's still there, in the repository.  It's just that if we ask Git to *find* commits, Git is going to start with the name `master`, then *work backwards*.  We'll see commit `B`, then we'll see commit `A`, and then Git will stop because there is no earlier commit.

If we remember the hash ID of commit `C`, we can put it back with another `git reset --hard`, making the name `master` point to `C` again:

```
     C   <-- master
    /
A--B
```

and now we can draw them as a straight line again.

#### Commits are therefore the snapshots *and* the history

So that shows us the point of commits: they hold the snapshots of all the files, and because they connect to each other—though backwards only—they *are* the history.  It also shows us the point of branch names: the name *finds* the *last* commit that is part of the branch.  From there, Git works backwards.

#### Commits can be on many branches

If we have this:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

as our history so far, we can now make a *new* branch name, also pointing to commit `C`.  Let's use the name `develop`:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop, master
```

To make it easy to tell which *name* we're using, let's attach a special name, `HEAD`, to exactly one *branch* name, like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop, master (HEAD)
```

This means we're using commit `C` through name `master`.  If we run:

```
git checkout develop    # or git switch develop
```

now, we get:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop (HEAD), master
```

Nothing *else* changes: we are still using commit C.  But now we're using commit `C` through the *name* `develop`.

This matters when we make our *next* commit.  We modify some file, run `git add`, and run `git commit` and get a new commit `D`.  New commit `D` points back to existing commit `C`, and **Git stores the new commit hash ID into the current branch name**, so now we have:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

Commits `A-B-C` were on both branches before.  They're *still* on both branches *now*, but now new commit `D` is *only* on `develop`.

If we go back to `master`, create yet another new branch, and make yet more commits, we get:

```
        E--F--G   <-- feature (HEAD)
       /
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- develop
```

and so on.  *Checking out* (or switching to) a branch name means: *Remove all the files from the current commit, and instead put in the files from the commit pointed-to by the branch name, and make that the current branch.*  Making a new *branch* means: *Make a new name, pointing to some commit.*  We pick which commit before we make the name, usually by checking it out first (so that we can see if it's the right one).

#### We're now ready for `git merge`

Let's suppose we have this going on:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

That is, we have three branch names, each of which points to a different "last" commit.  The last commit on `branch1` is `J`; the last commit on `branch2` is `L`; and the last commit on `master` is `H`, which—along with all earlier commits—is on *all three* branches.

If we now run:<sup>1</sup>

```
git merge --ff-only branch1
```

our Git will locate, in this repository, *three* commits.  These three commits are:

- The *current commit*.  This one is easy to find, because Git just uses `HEAD` as usual.  Since `HEAD` is attached to `master`, and `master` finds commit `H`, this finds commit `H`.
- The *other commit* that we name on the command line.  Since we said `branch1`, Git reads `branch1` to see that it points to commit `J`.
- Last—or in some sense first, because of the way Git does merges, but Git has to find the other two before it can find this most important commit on its own—Git uses these two commits to find the *best shared commit*.  The best shared commit is a commit that is on *both* branches, and is better than any other commit also on both branches.

Git calls this best shared commit the *merge base*.  Technically, the merge base is the commit that comes out of the [Lowest Common Ancestor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor#Extension_to_directed_acyclic_graphs) algorithm, but a good way to *see* it is that it's the commit "closest" to both branch tip commits.  Here, that's just commit `H` itself, which is as close as you can get to commit `H`, and as close as any *shared* commit is to commit `L`.

When the merge base of a `git merge` command *is* the *current commit*, Git can do what it calls a *fast-forward merge*.  This isn't really a merge at all: it's more just a `git checkout`, but it's a `git checkout` that drags the *branch name* with it.  That is, the result of any *real* merge would just match commit `L`, as we'll see in a moment.  So instead of bothering with a real merge, if you let it, Git will do this fake non-merge fast-forward thing instead.

The result is this:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1, master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

Note that commit `H` is *not* abandoned!  We still find commit `H`, but now we find it whether we start from `J` because of the name `branch1`, or whether we start from `J` because of the name `master`.  Either way, Git steps back once to commit `I`, then again to commit `H`.  So now, commits up through `J` are *on both branches*.

You should repeat that to yourself because it's big and important: **Commit `J` used to be only on `branch1`.  Now it's on both branches.**  The branches that contain some commit *change* over time.

Now we'll run a second `git merge`, this time using:

```
git merge branch2
```

When Git goes to do this one, it again locates the three commits: the current commit `J`, the other commit `L`, and the merge base.  The merge base is the *best shared commit*, so, which commits are *shared?*  It should be obvious from looking at the diagram: as before, that's commits up through and including `H`.  The *best* one is commit `H` again.

This time, Git cannot take a short-cut.  To do a merge, Git has to do a *real* merge.

---

<sup>1</sup>The `--ff-only` is usually unnecessary.  It tells Git that we want the fast-forward that Git uses by default.  If you've configured certain Git settings, this `--ff-only` will override that configurations, which is why I included it here.

---

#### Merge is about combining work

We already noted that each Git commit contains a *full snapshot of every file*.  There aren't any *changes* in any commit.  There is only a *snapshot*, plus the metadata.  To find changes, then, we have to have Git *compare* two snapshots.

We can, for instance, have Git compare the snapshot in commit `H` to that in commit `I`.  Any files that are exactly the same are *unchanged*.  Any files that are different have some changes, and Git can compare each file to see *what changed*.  That's how Git shows us what *changed* in commit `I`: by comparing its snapshot to the snapshot in `H`.

The same goes for commit `J`, though we'll have to have Git compare its snapshot against the one in commit `I`.  Put those two sets of changes together, and you get the overall change from `H` to `J`.

Git *can* take one small shortcut here: instead of comparing `H` vs `I`, then `I` vs `J`, Git can just compare `H` vs `J` directly.  Whatever files are the same, those didn't change.  Whatever files are different, Git can figure out what's different *in* those files.  This is faster and easier, especially if commit `J` *un*-does any changes made in commit `I`.  But in any case, that's what Git does.  In effect, it runs `git diff`:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what we changed
```

This tells Git what we changed in our `master` branch.

Then, Git does the same kind of diff, starting from the same merge base commit `H`, but to the *other* commit:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # what they changed
```

Git now has to *combine* these two sets of changes.

That's what `git merge` is really about.  We run two diffs—from the shared merge base to each branch tip—to see what we changed, and what they changed, and then we combine those two diffs.  Or rather, we have Git do all that, and then we have Git *apply* the *combined* changes to the snapshot from `H`, the merge base.

By taking our changes and adding theirs—or equivalently, taking their changes and adding ours—we get *both changes*.  We keep ours, and add theirs.  When Git does this combining, it uses some very simple text-oriented rules: each change is just *delete these lines and add these other lines*.  As long as some file that we and they both touched has these changes done far enough apart, Git will be able to combine them on its own.

If Git *can't* combine these changes on its own, Git will give up, stop in the middle of the merge, and leave us a mess to fix.  But in many cases, Git can combine them on its own, and does.  That's true even though Git has no idea what it's doing: it does not *understand* our files in any way.  It's just following simple text rules.  And yet, that actually works, quite often.

Having combined both changes and applied them to the snapshot from `H`, Git now makes a new commit, mostly as usual:

- The *snapshot* for the new commit is the result of applying the combined changes.
- The *parent* of the new commit is where things are a little odd.

Instead of just the one usual parent, Git adds a *second* parent to this new commit:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- master (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

New merge commit `M` points back to commit `J` as usual, but *also* points back to commit `L`.  The result is that *all the commits are now on `master`*.  Commits up through `J` are on `branch1`; commits up through `H`, plus `K-L`, are on `branch2`; and all commits up through and including merge commit `M` are on `master`.

#### Merging therefore makes commits "more reachable"

Merge commits, then, have this interesting side effect of making commits that were just on one branch, be on more than one branch.  Even non-merge commits—from the fast-forward we did earlier—did the same thing: it added commit `I-J` to `master`.

Note that if we *could* do a fast-forward merge:

```
...--D--E   <-- mainline (HEAD)
         \
          F--G--H   <-- feature
```

we can tell Git: *do a real merge*, using `git merge --no-ff feature`.  In this case, Git will find the merge base commit `E`, the current commit `E`, and the other commit `H`, and say to itself: *I could do a fast-forward, but the user commanded that I do a real merge.*  So Git will dutifully run:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-E> <hash-of-E>   # what we changed
```

to figure out what we changed.  The output of this diff is ... nothing!

Git then does the other diff, to find out they changed, and combines the two diffs.  The combination of "nothing" and "anything" is the anything, so the result of the combining is a set of changes that will turn commit `E`'s snapshot into commit `H`'s.  Git will then make a new *merge commit* with the snapshot from `H`:

```
...--D--E---------M   <-- mainline (HEAD)
         \       /
          F--G--H   <-- feature
```

and make new merge commit `M`—I used that letter to stand for *merge* again, this time—such that it has `E` as its first parent and `H` as its second parent.  The snapshot *in* new commit `M` is exactly the same as the snapshot *in* existing commit `H`, but since we told Git *do not use the fast-forward short-cut*, it made a real merge commit.

(You should do this—the *make a real merge commit*—if you want the *hash ID* of commit `M` to be *different* from the hash ID of existing commit `H`, and to have two parents like this, so that you can see that there was a merge.  If you *don't care* whether the hash IDs match and whether there's a real merge, you can let Git do the fast-forward thing instead, which is easier on Git.  The difference will be that some future historian, looking at your repository, won't know that you got there by using a fast-forward merge: if you make a real merge, that records the real merge, for that future historian to see.)

#### That was a lot of background; now we can get back to your question

> I have to checkout to master and pull changes, but in those changes, a few of the files I was working on have been removed and new files made.

So, this means that you have, at the moment, your own branch name and your own commits:

```
          I--J   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
```

You're going to run `git checkout master`, which will do this:

```
          I--J   <-- somebranch
         /
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Then you're going to run `git pull`.  This will:

1. Run `git fetch`, which will obtain new commits from some other Git repository:

   ```
             I--J   <-- somebranch
            /
   ...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
            \
             K--L   <-- origin/master
   ```

   We haven't covered *remote-tracking names* like `origin/master`, but it will remember the hash ID of the newest commit you got from *their* `master` branch.
2. Run `git merge origin/master`, probably, depending on how you configured your Git defaults.  Assuming it does, and that this permits and thus does a fast-forward merge, you will end up with:

   ```
             I--J   <-- somebranch
            /
   ...--G--H--K--L   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
   ```

   in your repository.

Note how none of *your* commits has changed.  They literally *can't*.  You will, however, want to do something with them.

The tricky part is now *what to do with your commits*, `I-J` here.  You can *merge* or *rebase*.  Merging is fundamentally simpler and is what we have already covered, so let's look at what this does.  If you run:

```
git checkout somebranch && git merge master
```

you'll start with:

```
          I--J   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H--K--L   <-- master, origin/master
```

Your Git now has to *combine the changes*.  You made some changes to some file(s), between your best shared commit `H` and your current commit `J`.  They made some changes to some file(s) between `H` and `L`, and their changes include *removing entire files*, so that commit `L` lacks some files as compared to commit `H`.

Git will do its best to combine your changes with theirs.  If you've *changed* the file that they *removed*, Git's attempt to combine changes will *fail*.  Git does not know how to combine *add this line, remove that one* with *remove the entire file*.

If you *have not* changed the file that they removed, Git will combine *do nothing* with *remove entire file* and will remove the file.  That's fine!

If the merge *fails*, Git will stop with a *merge conflict*.  You will now have to fix up the result yourself.  Whatever files you supply as the "correct result", *Git will believe you*.

If the merge *succeeds*, Git will go ahead and make a new merge commit:

```
          I--J--M   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
         /     /
...--G--H--K--L   <-- master, origin/master
```

In this case, if you want some file back, simply *extract that file from an earlier commit* such as commit `J`.  Find the commit's hash ID and run, e.g.:<sup>2</sup>

```
git restore --source <hash-of-J> -SW -- path/to/file.ext
```

and Git has now copied the file from commit `J` to both its index / staging-area, and to your working tree.  If your Git is old and does not have `git restore`, use the equivalent `git checkout`:

```
git checkout <hash-of-J> -- path/to/file.ext
```

which does the same thing (in old *and* new Git versions), and is shorter.<sup>3</sup>

If the merge *does* fail with a merge conflict, and Git stops and needs your help to finish the merge, you get to learn all about resolving Git merge conflicts.

---

<sup>2</sup>There are ways to do this without having to cut and paste hash IDs, but as a Git beginner, rest assured that cutting and pasting hash IDs is fine.  I still do it myself sometimes; sometimes it's the easiest thing!  Just run `git log` to find the right commit, then cut and paste.

<sup>3</sup>The `git checkout` method is just something of a bad habit, because `git checkout` has a "safe mode" and an "unsafe mode".  The new-in-Git-2.23 `git switch` command always works in "safe mode"; the unsafe parts from `git checkout` are now in the new `git restore` command.  That way you always know whether you're running a "safe" command (`git switch`) or an "unsafe" one (`git restore`).  With the old `git checkout`, it's hard to know whether you're using it in safe mode or unsafe mode.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `git merge {branch}`. So if you want to merge your changes into master branch, do:

```
git checkout master
git merge yourBranch
```

You can read more about Branches and Merging here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging